# Parallel execution causing test data mixing across tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm automating Selenium tests using TestNG's `data-provider-thread-count` which runs tests in parallel. But I could see that username, password of one test i.e. driver is being passed to another one.

I analyzed my code and there I could see that for each thread I've `Webdriver` instance and there is no objects which are shared across, hence I think there is no chance of sharing test data of test with another.

Could you please let me know what could be other possible reasons so accordingly I'll analyze my code and try to find root cause?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Add ThreadGuard when you are instantiating the driver .  WebDriver driver = ThreadGuard.protect(new FirefoxDriver()); https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ThreadGuard.html If there is exception then your webdriver is not threadsafe

Comment: @RahulL, thanks for the details! I'll give a try with this.

Comment: @RahulL, with ThreadGuard browser is not loading all the contents and hence unable to find some elements(run this several times and each time saw same behaviour). And if we remove ThreadGuard all the elements are loaded and tests continue.

Comment: @TDHM - Please edit your post and add the problematic code in question so that we can find out what is going wrong (Please clean up the code and post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) version of your code.

Comment: @TDHM ThreadGuard does not have any overhead or effect on loading of elements. Please share mcve version of you code